# ArcGIS Pro Spatial Join polygon "Within" two polygons

Tags: polygon, arcgis-pro, spatial-join

[image]

Spatial Join of Counties and Places, highlighted polygon place falls within 2 counties (pink) within returns null on the match.

If a polygon crosses the border of 2 polygons in a spatial join is within false?

If I use intersect, it comes back with Places that share borders and are not within a county polygon. Ultimate goal is to have unique record for Place/County combination.

Comment: Welcome to GIS stack exchange! In order to help you, could you edit your question and add an example of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Suggest you read the help file for the tool, specifically the [parameter](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm#GUID-935E7B88-CC21-4558-AD29-143C6B5D55E9) section, it clearly explains the different options.

Comment: "Share borders" is not a "Within" relationship. To be Within, a feature must be wholly contained. But you don't want a "Within" relationship -- place/county relationships require an "Intersects" with a non-zero area of intersection.

Comment: @vince Is there a tool for this, I am new to ARC Gis so I apoligize if this is a dumb question. On A spatial join intersects doesnt provide a way to get or set area of intersection.

Comment: The Intersect command, followed by Summary Statistics will likely get you what you need (one tool solutions are rare in "I want to do *this* then *that*" situations).

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with polygons most of yesterday and found the details around selection from this page very helpful. I know it's not specifically the answer, but you might be able to get there from here:

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/select-by-location-graphical-examples.htm

[image]

[image]